# Creating a fetch wrapper in Typescript

Tags: typescript, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a wrapper for fetch in TypeScript but I can't get the typings right:

```
export interface ResponsePromise extends Promise<Response> {
  arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
  blob(): Promise<Blob>;
  formData(): Promise<FormData>;
  json<T>(): Promise<T>;
  text(): Promise<string>;
}

class Api {
  public get(url: string, params = {}): ResponsePromise {
    const body = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    return fetch(url, {method: 'GET', body});
  }
}

const foo = async () => {
  const api = new Api();
  await api.get('http://www.example.com').json<any>();
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWAGdIkjgAFKCAWwXLlFSQBMi4rb7gAeQkiGWAA+OAG8AUHDiYoUTAE8AQgFd06NAAoAlAC4O1OuR4BBOYtXq0wgNxS4AIwA2EBzv2cjvJS4e376NA0ACKYMJjuBlzGAGJBoeH+0gBWRII8ACrCkZ7cmUlwqCAwOYZ5RDBQyADm-gC+EhLYTphE7CZgCOL2YCrOCNhw1cAlKlBO+hVVSNUANHBgspg07AC84nV6BMSk5LkMktLS2IIVjhAsCnDrSMAA7nAAqvgAMgDKwLLYABYUSyuaRbyFbaAB0MAgb0qNR0diOcCgIzGSDgGhgP00Yyc8zENBG3wu+gA5ABxACiGSJ8wcFwUmzhcAaDSap3ggQg1xkRAUSEGOmuokOcBOZHgmE6nNuDw6CFh9kwd0wCDFnVBwxKRO+MBgYF0AHo9XcjaDQMswE5gKCTjQiWDUulMEgFNltHY6kA)

Comment: Regarding default fetch arguments, as per 2023, according to [lib/dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts) it is `(input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit)`. This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript *already* has typings for `fetch` that you can reuse:

- `RequestInfo` for the `input` parameter (you've called it `url`, but `fetch` calls it `input` [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method)], and it may not be a string)
- `RequestInit` for the optional `init` parameter (you don't seem to be using that in your `get`)
- `Response` for the response.

So:

```
class Api {
  public get(input: RequestInfo, params = {}): Promise<Response> {
    const body = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    return fetch(input, {method: 'GET', body});
  }
}
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> how do I allow the user to simply call `await api.get().json()`?

That's a very different question than a question about types. You'd probably still return `Promise<Response>`, but you'd implement the first-level `then` handler within `get` (I do this anyway, because the `fetch` API is flawed, encouraging lots of failures to handle errors as [I describe here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).) So for instance:

```
class Api {
  public async get(input: RequestInfo, params = {}): Promise<Response> {
    const body = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    const response = await fetch(input, {method: 'GET', body});
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

Since `Response` implements `Body`, it has `json()` etc. on it. If you wanted, you could return `Promise<Body>` instead and return `.body`:

```
class Api {
  public async get(input: RequestInfo, params = {}): Promise<Body> {
    const body = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    const response = await fetch(input, {method: 'GET', body});
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.body;
  }
}
```

...but I don't think that buys you anything.

Comment: Yes but (and maybe I should have pointed this out in the question) how do I allow the user to simply call `await api.get().json()`?

Comment: @OskarPersson - That's a very different question than a question about types. I've updated the answer.

Comment: the examples requires me to write `(await api.get('http://www.example.com')).json();` instead of simply `await api.get('http://www.example.com').json();` Which I would like to avoid. Also, I can't require and set typing of the json response. Like I do in my example. Maybe I should rewrite my question.

Comment: @OskarPersson - True, it does. That's because there are *two* levels of promise (the response, and reading the body). The only way to actually do `api.get(...).json()` is to: 1. Implement `json` on the promise returned by the function, hiding an implementation detail. I wouldn't do that. 2. Pass in the response method you want to use and call it within `get`. 3. Have multiple functions (`getJSON`, `getArrayBuffer`, ...).

Comment: Somehow [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) is able to do this but I can't figure out what it exactly is that they do to make it work

Comment: They basically do #1 above, but not on a promise, on a Ky object. You could have `get` return an object with those methods on it, and have it internally consume the first promise. But this is pretty far from the question about types.